# how to hit pycharm django server from outside

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm

I have a django site running on ubuntu in a virtualbox installed on a windows 7 machine. I have NAT with port forwarding. I can hit the nginx/uwsgi server from other machines/tablets within my LAN. To debug the site in pycharm, I stop nginx and uwsgi and use pycharm's django server and I can step through the code if I hit the server from a browser in ubuntu. However, for some reason, I can't hit pycharm's django server from a browser outside of ubuntu.

This is very strange to me. I don't have a networking problem because I can hit the nginx server just fine. Pycharm's django server works fine because I can hit it from a browser within ubuntu. I don't under why I can't hit pycharm's django server from outside just like I can the nginx server.

Can someone provide an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:port`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, django runs on the IP address 127.0.0.1(pycharm probably does the same thing).

That ip can not be visited by external network. Your host os's network is external to the guest vm's network.

You can run django runserver on `0.0.0.0` and allow any external network to visit your dev site.

Answer (score 6):

First you should get the IP address of your virtual machine. In Ubuntu, run the command "ifconfig" in your terminal.

Then, in PyCharm do the following steps:
 - Go to the menu Run > Run... > Edit Configurations
 - Click the '+' button and select Django server
 - Name it and fill the field "Host" by the IP address you just got in the first step
 - Click Run

Finally if your IP Address was 192.168.1.10, in your external browser go to:

```
http://192.168.1.10:8000
```

Comment: "Tools > Run manage.py task ... > runserver" and "Run > Run..." are essentially the same thing except "Run > Run..." lets you set options.